# Equidistant radio buttons across div

Tags: html, css, alignment

I'm trying to span a dynamic amount of radio buttons across the entire width of a div without the use of tables (if possible).  I don't want a clump of them to the left of the div, the right, or the middle, but I want them equally spaced along the width, with whitespace the same on either side of every single button.

```
<div style='width:100%'>
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Can this be done in CSS?  If not, is the best alternative to use a table?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This won't work in < IE8. You could provide a conditional comment stylesheet fallback, perhaps by floating them.

#### Example

[image: Example]

#### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div><input type="radio"></div>
    <div><input type="radio"></div>
    <div><input type="radio"></div>
    <div><input type="radio"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
#container {
    display: table;  
    width: 100%;
}

#container div {
    display: table-cell; 
    text-align: center;
}
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YUZbf/).

[Test it by adding new elements](http://jsfiddle.net/alexdickson/YUZbf/1/).

Answer (score 0):

You may also want to try this version as well since it is a bit flexible if you decide to add more radios later on and it works on any browser thanks to jQuery. Yeah, I know, JavaScript for presentation purposes...{shutter}!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    // get width of containing div
    var width = $('#radios_group').width();
    // get the number of radios in this group
    var count = $('#radios_group input[type=radio]').length
    // width of each element (take 5 extra pixels off to account for variations)
    var radio_width = parseInt(width / count) - 5;

    // loop over each radio and set it to the new width
    $('#radios_group input[type=radio]').each(function(){
        $(this).width(radio_width);
    });
});
</script>

<div id="radios_group" style='width:100%'>
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
  <input type="radio">
</div>
```

Comment: Besides browser support, it is less flexible when adding new `radio` inputs (as you need to run this function again).